# Laravel / Kakao Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cache' not found

Tags: laravel, caching

I try to set up kakao login to my Shopify store, but when I run the test I encountered this message error, what should I do? Thank you

[image: You can see details here pls :)]

Comment: There's no reason to screenshot your code, upload it to an image hosting site and then link to that site when you can just copy paste the code in the question. Also try `\Cache`  instead of `Cache`

Comment: Try to check once is Cache class is imported into that controller or not - the error message implies it is not imported;

Answer (score 0):

The `Cache` facade doesn't live in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. If you do not include a `use` statement at the top of your PHP files for your classes, it is assumed the `class` **does** live in the same `namespace`.

The Laravel `Cache` facade lives in the `Illuminate\Support\Facades` `namespace` so at the top of your `KakaoController` with your other `use` statements, add the following:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must need to add "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;" on top of controller, middleware, command, event or blade files.

for example

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
class KaKaoController extends Controller {
...
```

or "use \Cache;"